# BasicAuth with rest controllers - denied access

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement Basic Auth (from Spring Security) to my newbie project. To create an user I send a JSON to `POST` at `/register`, then the user is created and put into H2 in-memory database - this part works fine. Then I have this method in my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
    return principal.getName();
}
```

which returns logged in person's name. I'm using Postman for this - just picking Basic Auth from the droplist, putting username and password of this created user (it is in the database, I checked) and I get Access Denied response - so I guess I'm not logging in correctly or maybe my Spring config isn't right?

I'm using Spring Boot and have 3 Spring Security configs:

**UserAuthService.java**

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserAuthService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserAuthService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find the user: " + username); 
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(),
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
    }
}
```

**AccountConfiguration.java**

```java
// Spring Security uses accounts from our database
@Configuration
public class AccountConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {


    private UserDetailsService userAuthService;

    @Autowired
    public AccountConfiguration(UserDetailsService userAuthService) {
        this.userAuthService = userAuthService;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userAuthService);
    }
}
```

And last one to just pick what is authorized and what isn't:

**WebConfiguration.java**

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // allow everyone to register an account; /console is just for testing
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/console/**").permitAll();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

        // making H2 console working
        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable();

        /*
        https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#when-to-use-csrf-protection
        for non-browser APIs there is no need to use csrf protection
        */
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Here is link to GitHub project if someone wants to check other configs - I'm new to this so maybe I didn't put something relevant in this post:
https://github.com/doublemc/ToDoWebApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure HTTP basic authentication in your Spring Security configuration, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity):

> **5.2 HttpSecurity**
>
> Thus far our WebSecurityConfig only contains information about how to authenticate our users. How does Spring Security know that we want to require all users to be authenticated? How does Spring Security know we want to support form based authentication? The reason for this is that the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` provides a default configuration in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method that looks like:
>
> ```java
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>   http
>       .authorizeRequests()
>           .anyRequest().authenticated()
>           .and()
>       .formLogin()
>           .and()
>       .httpBasic();
> }
> ```
>
> The default configuration above:
>
> - Ensures that any request to our application requires the user to be authenticated
> - Allows users to authenticate with form based login
> - Allows users to authenticate with HTTP Basic authentication

Your modified (and simplified) code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/console/**").permitAll();
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I have found is that the user need to be **fully authenticated** in order to access the resources because of this line:
`http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();`

Change it to:
`http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();`

`authenticated()` means user must **NOT** an anonymous or a remember-me user